# Do I need composer on TYPO3 production-system when my TYPO3 is in composer mode

Tags: deployment, composer-php, typo3

I use TYPO3 in composer-mode on my dev-system.
I will deploy by copying all generated files to production-system.

I'm wondering if I will need to have composer installed on my production system or is it sufficient when all the "vendor" / "autoload" stuff is just copied to production system.

In other words: does TYPO3 composer-mode require to have composer installed?

Many thanks for replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have correctly discovered you don't need Composer once all packages have been installed and autoload info has been dumped.

If you do all this locally or on a CI server and then upload all files, e.g. with `rsync` then you have a running compilation of your instance. There are no changes to packages or autoload info at runtime which could require Composer.

Answer (score 2):

No, composer is not required on the remote server.
Indeed, as long as you have all the required files like the vendor folder with all the autoload information it works.

For example if you use (default settings) TYPO3 Surf (https://github.com/TYPO3/Surf), the build is done locally and then all the files are uploaded to the remote server. This way there's no need for (for example) git or composer on the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the other way around and you should **not** have composer installed on production systems **at all**!

This way you reduce the risk of installing/upgrading compromised and/or broken packages, since you will be able to test changes on a local or staging environment first before deploying them to the production machine as described in the other answers.

Comment: I don't agree with that: there is nothing wrong in using Composer on a production system, if you use `composer install` and not `composer update`

Comment: Yes, you should always use `composer install` in this case. But as a matter of fact any additional piece of code on a production system raises the risk of security issues. Even if a CLI binary is not accessible or callable from the web there's always the danger that a unknown security hole makes use of it to perform malicious tasks.